# Gray Triangle in Top Right Corner of Excel Cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm getting this gray triangle in the top left corner of a cell in an excel document and cannot for the life of me find the cause of it - I'm using Excel 2016 on a Windows 10 Machine.

[image: Gray Triangle]

Comment: Can you select it? Is it always in the same cell? Is it only in one cell all in all cells?

Comment: @MátéJuhász unselectable, only in that cell

Comment: Is it that same cell on every sheet or just the one sheet you're looking at?

Comment: @blakeoft just the one sheet I'm looking at

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I just found out what caused it in my case.

I got these by copying and pasting from an old website into excel, probably the HTML code contained "something" which then got transferred into excel when <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.